# How to rename project and release in CM synergy

Tags: rename, cm-synergy

I need to rename one of the synergy project along with the release. One of the option is to create a separate project and copy the contents in synergy. But doing so hampers the release notes , which shows the changes as entire check-ins so far. And updating the release note scripts is not an option , because of business reasons:(

Could any one let me know if renaming project is possible . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't rename a project or release in synergy.

The closest I've been able to do is create a new release with your current release as the predecessor. Then create a new project with your new name and copy the contents of the old project inside the synergy gui. Copying inside the gui keeps the instance the same, so you don't lose file history.